# How can I make UIAlertView modal?

Tags: ipad, ios5, objective-c-2.0

I want to show a login dialogue and login error dialogue if necessary.

I use UIAlertView to show these dialogues, but the process keep running while showing the UIAlertView.

I wrote a code below. Now NSUserDefaults doesn't keep those value, so I expected login dialogue is shown and wait until button to be tapped.

But when run this, error dialogue is shown and after tapping OK for this, login dialogue is shown.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)storeEvernote
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    evID = [defaults stringForKey:@"evID"];
    evPW = [defaults stringForKey:@"evPW"];
    NSLog(@"%@", evID);

    if( evID == NULL || evPW == NULL )
    {
        login = true;
        [self showLoginDialogue];
    }
    else
    {
        evernoteID = evID;
        evernotePW = evPW;
    }
    if( evernoteID == NULL || evernotePW == NULL )
    {
        login = false;
        [self showErrMessage];
        return;
    }
    [self getEvernoteNotebooks];
}

- (void)showLoginDialogue
{
    UIAlertView *loginDialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Evernote Login"     message:@"Enter your Evernote Info" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
    loginDialogue.delegate = self;
    loginDialogue.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;

    [loginDialogue show];
}

- (void)showErrMessage
{
    UIAlertView *loginalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failure" message:@"Invalid ID & Password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [loginalert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time that `storeEvernote` method runs, `evID` and `evPW` are `NULL` so the first `if` is true, it shows the `LoginDialoge` then it continues to second `if` and because `evernoteID` and `evernotePW` are still `NULL` so the condition in second `if` statement is also true, so it shows the `errorMessage`. To fix this, move the second `if` statement to delegate method of the `loginDialogue` ALSO ADD `return;` to the end of first `if` statement for example:

```
- (void)storeEvernote
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    evID = [defaults stringForKey:@"evID"];
    evPW = [defaults stringForKey:@"evPW"];
    NSLog(@"%@", evID);
if( evID == NULL || evPW == NULL )
{
    login = true;
    [self showLoginDialogue];
    return;
}
else
{
    evernoteID = evID;
    evernotePW = evPW;
}

[self getEvernoteNotebooks];
}

//The login dialoge delegate method:

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   //Process user input
      ...
   if( evernoteID == NULL || evernotePW == NULL )
    {
        login = false;
        [self showErrMessage];
        return;
    }
    [self getEvernoteNotebooks];
}
```

Comment: Zeus,Thank you very much for your sample code.

It worked perfect and solved my problem.

I didn't know that application keep running while showing UIAlertView.

Comment: Your welcome:) Please click on the check mark icon on the left side of answer to mark this as correct answer.